# How to get the Count of an Entity Framework Junction Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two simple tables, `Users` and `Roles`.  Both have their own Primary Key called `ID` along with a few other unique properties that have nothing to do with this question.  Both tables also have a `virtual IList` property of the other.  So a `User` object as the following property:

```
public virtual IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

And the `Role` object has the following property:

```
public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Both allow me to navigate from a `User` to their `Role`s or from a `Role` to its `User`s with ease in C#.

The `EntityTypeConfiguration` for the `Role` has nothing specific to the `User`.  However, the `User` has the following for the `Role` to create the Junction table:

```
  this.HasMany(x => x.Roles)
    .WithMany(x => x.Users)
    .Map(x => {
      x.ToTable("UserRole", "xref");
      x.MapLeftKey("UserID");
      x.MapRightKey("RoleID");
    });
```

This behaves perfectly for everything I needed to do, up to this point.  Now, I need a way to query the total number of records in that `xref.UserRole` table.  In SQL I would simply do the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xref.UserRole
```

and life would be perfect.  But EF takes that Junction table and puts it behind the scenes.  I have no way to do something like:

```
int TotalJoins = db.UserRoles.Count();
```

I have looked all over here and the web and am not finding anything that is specific to a simple Junction table like this.  Other answers have extra fields or is not a true many-to-many join so it will not work in my case.

Is there a way, with some extension method or deeper property on the DbContext to get to that table so I can use it in a Linq query?  I know I can write a Stored Procedure, but that seems a bit of a kluge.

Comment: The question is why do you need to know or should you care about such a thing in the first place?  If you really really need to know (which you shouldn't), then you can do a `context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xref.UserRole");` or something similar.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I appreciate your quick response and answer.  Although I might go as far as saying since you have never needed to know that count does not mean it "shouldn't" be known.  The client wants to know the total number of "joins" within their UI.  The client pays the bills.  Thank you just the same sir.

Comment: Well I would say that it is an artifact of the implementation of many-to-many joins for an object model in the current implementation of SQL.  The fact that you want to know about an artifact means that you are intentionally trying to break the conceptual model, which isn't usually a good thing.  That said, @DStanley has the answer that doesn't break the conceptual model, and gets you the answer you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need a way to query the total number of records in that `xref.UserRole` table

So what you're *really* looking for is the total number of roles assigned to all users.  That could be computed as:

```
db.Users.Sum(u => u.Roles.Count());
```

although I'd be surprised if that was actually translated to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xref.UserRole
```

If you want to run *that exact query* you can always use `SqlQuery`.

Comment: That first one works.  Shortly after I posted my question I did one last ditch effort and came up with this which also works.  `var Count = db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any()).Count();` I would almost guess that yours @DStanley is probably quicker, without getting the SQL it generates.  Thank you!

Comment: @Grandizer Well, that would be different - that would be the numbers of _users_ that have at least one role.  It will not give you the total number of  records in the join table.